# IIS Rewrite rule based on length param

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rule

```
<rule name="Product short redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="product/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent"  url="product-redirect/?code={R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

However i want it only to match product codes that are longer than 3 characters

```
<rule name="Product short redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="product/([A-Za-z0-9].{4}+)/$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent"  url="product-redirect/?code={R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

But this only returns a partial match and also the three characters codes still match ??

Sample partial urls will be:

```
product/u22tfp1/
```

and

```
product/xxx/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only match products that are 4 characters or more, you need to specify the length on the regular expression:

E.G: Want a match of (`products/1234/` OR `products/12345/` )

```
<match url="product\/([A-Za-z0-9]{4,100}+)\/$" />
```

I use a match between 4 and 100 on this example (you can also explicitly avoid a match with 3 characters, but it looks uglier on my opinion)

NOTE:
The problem with the previous regular expression `product/([A-Za-z0-9].{4}+)/$` is the dot character `.` that matches everything, basically you are saying match:

```
 "product/" then 
 "a single character/digit [a-Z0-9]" then 
 "anything with a length of 4"(repeat this last statement "+" )
```