# IIS Url rewrite rule with request max lenght

Tags: windows, iis, web, url-rewriting

Based on this question:
[IIS Rewrite rule based on length param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364391/iis-rewrite-rule-based-on-length-param)
In windows server 2012 IIS, I would like to create a rule that check for the first parameter only for "n" max digits.

the answer proposed gives me an error,

> `<match url="product\/([A-Za-z0-9]{4,100}+)\/$" />`
>
> throws this error:
>
> The expression contains a repeat expression (one of '', '?', '+', '{'
>   in most contexts) that is not preceded by an expression.

someone else have an idea to resolve?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp should be like that: `product\/([A-Za-z0-9]{4,100})\/$`

You shouldnt use `+` if you specified length `{4,100}`

Comment: Yes ok now the error was gone away, thank you, but... I thought that this rule ignoring the digits that go over 100 character, while In the test I see that the digits from 4 to 100 goes to {R:1} and the digits from 100 to over goes in the next {R:2}. Do you think is possible to make a rule if the digits are from 4-100 goes in {R:1} and if it pass the 100 digits goes in an error page or not considering the rule anymore? sorry but is difficult to explain well :-)

Comment: I tested it. And this regexp matches only if digits fro m4 to 100. If you will have 101 digits, then rule will be skipped